# Appendix change numbering

Tags: overleaf

I'm using this package \usepackage[toc,page]{appendix} to craete an appendix page. The numbering for each section is showing in the picture below[image] Can i change this to display the numbering in a format like 1,2..so on. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing a working example it is difficult to help.

For articles, you'll have to use `section`-commands.

For reports and books, however `chapter`-commands are preferred.

## Article classes

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[page,toc]{appendix}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First Section}
\subsection{First Subsection}
\section{Second Section}

\begin{appendices}
\section{Some Appendix}
Here be the appendix
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image: Article]

## Report or Book classes

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[page,toc]{appendix}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First Section}
\chapter{Second Chapter}

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Some Appendix}
Here be the appendix
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image: Report or Book]